# Running a segment of code in Parallel that is on a different file

Tags: parallel-processing

I am new to Parallel Programming and I am trying to run a segment (which is on a different file) this pseudocode in Parallel:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

// Initialise MPI
MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);


if (my_rank==0)
{
    // Some serial code goes here
}
while (abc ==YES){

if (xyz ==YES){ 
charges(times);
poisson (times);

}
}
if (my_rank==0)
{
    // Some more serial code goes here
}
MPI_Finalize();

return 0;

}`
```

I don't want to run the whole while loop in parallel, I just want to run a portion of poisson () function in parallel, which is defined in another file like this :

```
void poisson(){  
call_ellipti(); 
call_multigrid();
}
```

I am just willing to run this call_multigrid function in parallel. Can anyone give any hints how to do that? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I am totally not sure what to do as the poisson() and the call_multigrid functions are in a different file where there is no main function defined.

Comment: The usual approaches involve things like forking off threads and then waiting for them to join at the end. _However_, if you're using MPI, you really need to read the fine print on the MPI libraries and calls; they're not necessarily thread-safe. (It's theoretically possible to fork off completely separate processes as opposed to using threads, but getting the results back to the main process is potentially a lot of work -- particularly if you don't already have serialization implemented -- and well beyond the scope of a reasonable Stack Overflow question).